# ActionScript Netstream publish stage

Tags: actionscript, publish, stage, flash-media-server, netstream

is it possible to use NetStream to publish the stage constantly to a FMS?
I have tried to attach a camera to the netstream which works perfectly. However I want to publish a stream showing the stage and all its elements / objects including the case where a user interacts with the elements and changes their position/appearance.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As I know it's not possible this way.
You can't use a custom input for the netstream to encode it.

You have to following options:

- if you can reproduce the same elements on the other side, create an API, that only passes the interactions (i.e. drawLine(startX,startY,endX,endY), loadImage(url), etc). This way everything will be shown on both PC, with much less data traffic and CPU usage
- if you have a very complex stage and somehow it's impossible to reproduce it on the other side, then you can create bitmap shots, and send them through FMS JPEGencode (not too nice)
- use a webcam splitter that grabs the stage, and it can be a webcam source (not too nice)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The received stream is just being displayed in a web player. So what I need is a constant stream on the stage. Is this being done with FMS JPEGencode?